# Screen glitching when mousepad is tapped or keyboard is pressed

Tags: debian, video, keyboard, mouse, debian-stretch

I've been seeing graphics glitches in the last few days while using my Dell Inspiron I15-5558-D30 on Debian 9 (Stretch). It happens seldomly and only for a few seconds. Now it happened at the login screen and it would glitch whenever I tapped the mousepad or pressed a key in the keyboard. I've recorded a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBaMz-Rko_4

I have dual boot with Windows 7 and, so far, it haven't happened there.

What could it be? Should I worry?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I recorded a worse version of this glitch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upZ8n8aABM4

**Update:** forgot to say, I found the relevant bug report to this issue:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=878221

Comment: Does it also happen when you apply pressure on the case without touching keys or the touchpad? It looks a bit like loose display cable connection to me. But then again, you should see the same under Windows.

Comment: Tested, nothing happened.